# Jquery , incrementing class regex when class is not first

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a Field which is duplicated dynamically.
All is working fine, except I can not seem to change the class of the input field AND the parent span.

**Markup :**

```
<td class="small-text">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap submitted-file">
    <input type="file" name="submitted-file-1" value="1" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file submitted-file" id="submitted-file-1">
</span>
</td>
```

( Edit I : This is not the full markup, just the relevant part. The whole duplicated field is a full table row `<tr>` with id `#o99_the_work` as one can understand from the script.. )

**JS :**

```
jQuery("#add_row").click(function() {
    var row = jQuery("#o99_the_work tbody > tr:last"),
        newRow = row.clone(true);

    newRow.find("input[type=text],input[type=file]").each(function() {
        var me = jQuery(this).parent();
        var me2 = jQuery(this);
        var num = +(this.id.match(/\d+$/) || [0])[0] + 1;
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + num;
        this.name = this.id;
        me2.attr("class",me2.attr("class").replace(/\d+/, function(val) { return parseInt(val)+1; }));
    });

    newRow.insertAfter(row);

    return false;
});
```

So with this script, both `id` and `name` are incremented correctly.

Where is the problem then ? I need to increment also the class attribute `submitted-file` on both the input field and the parent span , but this line :

```
me2.attr("class",me2.attr("class").replace(/\d+/, function(val) { return parseInt(val)+1; }));
```

Actually catches the **FIRST** number , which in my case is `wpcf7-form-control` , and it is incrementing this value to  `wpcf8-form-control` , `wpcf9-form-control`.. (which is wrong for me )

How can I increment only the values that has `submitted-file[-something]`?

Comment: but `submitted-file-1` is an id, not a class

Comment: there is only `submitted-file` in class not `submitted-file-1`

Comment: @koala_dev ,user568109 - the `submtted-file` is a class , which  should become `submtted-file-1` `submtted-file-2` etc...

Comment: and may I ask why you need to update the classes? typically one would update name attributes,  I wouldn't even bother with using ids in this cases

Comment: This script is for some wordpress plugin called contact-form-7 (wpcf7) . The fields are upload fields which should be incremented . the plugin uses the class for identifying the fields and put them into array ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your regex in `replace()` method - you should search for the last occurence of the number.

```
me2.attr("class",me2.attr("class").replace(/\d+$/, function(val) { return parseInt(val)+1; }));
```

Comment: genious.. I always knew i had to learn regex.. But i guess I am not cut for it . A small `$`sign is all whats needed... :-) Thanks. works like a charm.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen you could also use `lastIndexOf()` and `substring()` but regex is more resilient to changes (e.g. if class name changes).